# How to implicitly stop a thread in an object in C#

Tags: c#, dispose

I have an object that contains a working thread. I'd like to kill the thread when the object is out of scope.

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace tt {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            AnotherClass a = new AnotherClass();
            a.Say();
        }

    }

    class AnotherClass:IDisposable {
        private bool m_Disposed;
        private readonly AutoResetEvent m_ResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        public AnotherClass() {
            Thread t = new Thread(wait);
            t.Start();
        }

        public void Dispose() {
            Dispose(true);
        }
        private void Dispose(bool disposing) {
            if (m_Disposed) {
                return;
            }

            if (disposing) {
                Console.WriteLine("inner disposing");
            }
            m_ResetEvent.Set();
            Console.WriteLine("Outer disposing");
            m_Disposed = true;
        }

        private void wait() {
            m_ResetEvent.WaitOne();
        }

        ~AnotherClass() {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Say() {
            Console.WriteLine("HellO");
        }
    }
}
```

The program will just hang in there because the destructor of AnotherClass is not called. I know I can call a.Dispose() to kill the thread. But is there a way to implicitly kill the thread when the object goes out of scope?

Comment: i think the only way to implicitly stop a thread is to disconnect power.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that's not possible. There is no reference counting that can notice that the object has no more references, so there is no way to do anything when that happens.

The `IDisposable` interface is used for classes that needs to do something when an instance is not going to be used any more, and calling the `Dispose` method is how you signal that you are done with the instance.

The usual way to make sure that an object is disposed when you leave a scope is to wrap the code in a `using` block:

```
static void Main()
{
  using (AnotherClass a = new AnotherClass())
  {
    a.Say();
  }
}
```

The `using` block is syntactic sugar for a `try...finally` block:

```
static void Main()
{
  AnotherClass a = new AnotherClass();
  try
  {
    a.Say();
  }
  finally
  {
    if (a != null)
    {
      ((Idisposable)a).Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ye gods and little fishes, I love `using`. Remembering to call `Dispose` isn't any trouble, but `using` just looks so damn elegant in code.

Comment: so if AnotherClass is a library, there's no way to ensure that the user closes / disposes AnotherClass properly?

Comment: @MonsterHunter If it implements IDisposable then there is. If you do not have access to the logic in the other class and IT doesn't dispose properly, then you might look into another library.

Comment: @MonsterHunter: Yes, that's right. There is no way to ensure that the programmer uses the class correctly. That is actually a quite common problem. The `IDisposable` pattern has a finalizer method (destructor) as a fallback to make the best of that situation. The garbage collector will call the finalizer before removing the object, which saves a lot of programs from leaking. I've seen examples of code running for years without disposing objects properly, and then suddenly fail when the amount of objects waiting to be collected grew too big.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Guffa's answer, I think it's also important to note that ***even if*** you had a way to detect the precise moment that your `AnotherClass` instance went out out scope, in this case, it just never will. And that's why you noticed that your destructor never got called.

The reason for that is that when you create and start your working thread, the thread is passed a delegate reference pointing to the instance method `wait()` which comes with an implicit reference to `this` (the `AnotherClass` instance).  So as long as your thread does not itself go out of scope, it will hold a strong reference to the `AnotherClass` instance and prevent it from getting garbage collected.

Comment: Then how do I make sure that the AntherClass will not cause the program to hangup without touching the code in the Program Class?

Comment: Based on the information available, using the `IDisposable` pattern as suggested by Guffa is the best way to go.  But you are also correct in that if the caller doesn't call `Dispose()`, then it won't work.  There are some workarounds that involve using the finalizer, but those options are rarely a good idea and can lead to other more serious problems.  If I was in your shoes, I would consider changing my class design.  But without knowing what your business requirements are, it's hard to suggest a better design alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You could use exception handling and use the error displayed as the exception in the catch block

Answer (score 1):

If your thread exists for the purpose of serving an object for the benefit of other threads, you should have a public-facing wrapper object to which all threads that are "interested" in the service will hold strong references, and the service itself will hold a long weak reference.  That wrapper object should not hold any information that the service needs to read or manipulate, but should instead forward all requests for information to an object which both the wrapper and the service hold strong references.

When the server thread is awake, it should periodically check whether the weak reference to the wrapper object is still alive.  If it isn't, the server thread should shut down in orderly fashion.  Note that the server never uses a strong reference to the wrapper object--even temporarily--so the wrapper object should evaporate as soon as nobody is interested in it.

If the server thread may be blocked indefinitely waiting for various things to happen, the wrapper should hold the only reference anywhere in the universe to a finalizable object which holds a strong reference to the server object; when the finalizer fires, it should check whether the long weak reference held by the server object is still valid.  If it isn't, it should try to nudge the server thread (e.g. using a `Monitor.TryEnter/Monitor.Pulse`.  If the wrapper object is still alive (finalizers can occasionally false-trigger in some resurrection scenarios) or the finalizer wasn't able to nudge the server thread, the finalizable object should re-register for finalization.

Using the finalizer object will complicate things; if the server thread can awaken itself periodically without needing to be nudged, that will simplify the design.  A finalizer used as described, however, should be relatively robust even in scenarios involving involuntary resurrection.